# Save powerpoint selected slides to desktop or desired location

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I have below code that save powerpoint to documents folder by default i woul like to save it in desktop or give an option to select folder to save it.

```
    private void SaveSelectedSlide_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
      try
        {
            PowerPoint.Application ppApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            PowerPoint.SlideRange ppslr = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange;
            string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            var temporaryPresentation = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Presentations.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout = ppApp.ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];

            for (int i = 1; i <= ppslr.Count; i++)
            {
                var sourceSlide = ppslr[i];
                sourceSlide.Copy();

                var design = sourceSlide.Design;
                temporaryPresentation.Slides.Paste();          

            }
            temporaryPresentation.SaveAs("Temporary", Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPresentation, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

            temporaryPresentation.Close();

        }
        catch (COMException Ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Some problem" + Ex.Message + Ex.StackTrace);
            MessageBox.Show("PLease enter text ");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The SaveAs method doesn't display the SaveAs dialog. You need to use the [FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744016(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Application class which returns a FileDialog object that represents a single instance of a file dialog box. For example:

```
Sub ShowSaveAsDialog()
    Dim dlgSaveAs As FileDialog
    Set dlgSaveAs = Application.FileDialog( _
        Type:=msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    dlgSaveAs.Show
End Sub
```

You may use any .Net components and class for implementing the required task in PowerPoint. For example, you can use the SaveAs dialog from BCLs. See [Powerpoint 2007 Save As Dialog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e2546c93-dccc-42c1-801c-bc01827e23df/powerpoint-2007-save-as-dialog?forum=vsto) for more information.